# How can I calculcate mean times in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this(every `date row` describes the moment of each event occured):

```
                          date
93286  2017-11-24 20:44:51.571              
93287  2017-11-24 20:45:01.571              
93288  2017-11-24 20:45:11.664      
93289  2017-11-24 20:45:21.664             
93290  2017-11-24 20:45:23.758        
93291  2017-11-24 20:45:34.071       
93292  2017-11-24 20:45:39.164        
93293  2017-11-24 20:45:44.664       
93294  2017-11-24 20:45:58.664        
93295  2017-11-24 20:46:54.774  
93296  2017-11-24 20:46:55.571
```

My goal is to calculate mean times per minute. So I thought I first need to subtract prior date from current date by `df['diff'] = df['date'] - df['date'].shift(1)`

```
                          date  diff
93286  2017-11-24 20:44:51.571  NaT   
93287  2017-11-24 20:45:01.571  00:00:10  
93288  2017-11-24 20:45:11.664  00:00:10.093   
93289  2017-11-24 20:45:21.664  00:00:10    
93290  2017-11-24 20:45:23.758  00:00:02.094
93291  2017-11-24 20:45:34.071  00:00:10.313
93292  2017-11-24 20:45:39.164  00:00:05.093
93293  2017-11-24 20:45:44.664  00:00:05.5
93294  2017-11-24 20:45:58.664  00:00:14      
93295  2017-11-24 20:46:58.774  00:00:00.11
93296  2017-11-24 20:46:59.571  00:00:00.797
```

But now I have no idea how to get a result that shows the average mean time of each minute like:

```
               date     mean
2017-11-24 20:45:00 8.386625
```

I tried using `pivot_table`, but it doesn't work this way.

```
>>> df.pivot_table(index=[pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1min')],aggfunc='mean')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "d:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3081, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'pivot_table'
```

How could I calculate mean times with with this dataframe?

Comment: Separate your date column and time column by splitting. Group by using the data column and take the mean of every group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `aggfunc=pd.Series.mean`, `'mean'` is maybe meant to be only for numerical datatypes  :

```
df.pivot_table(index=pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1min'),aggfunc=pd.Series.mean)

                             diff
date                               
2017-11-24 20:44:00             NaT
2017-11-24 20:45:00 00:00:08.386625
2017-11-24 20:46:00 00:00:28.453500
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me again! I works as I wanted! Have a good day! :)